# save my gpg file to a different directory

Tags: c#, windows, gnupg

I am working on a GPG encryption and want to save the file to a specific directory... can some one tell me how to do this..
i am using this code

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true


        };

        startInfo.FileName = "gpg.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-e -r myname config.xml";
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {

            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
```

when i do this it saves it to the APPdata folder is there a way i can change it to some default folder?

do i have to set some environmental variables to do this?

Please help me.. Let me know if I am not clear or i am missing something really stupid!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you simply prefix the output name with a path?

Comment: the config.xml is not the output name its the source file.. can u help me save the final encrypted file into a specific directory?

Comment: Did you read the help on the command line? http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Input-and-Output.html#GPG-Input-and-Output

Comment: i tried it @Erno but it dosent work with encrypt!

Comment: Did you add sufficient quotes so spaces in the path are handled correctly?

Comment: yes i used startInfo.Arguments ="-e -r Name config.xml -o c:\mytestfolder\config.xml.gpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true


        };

        startInfo.FileName = "gpg.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = @"-e -r myname c:\MYPATH\config.xml -o c:\MYPATH\config.xml.gpg";
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {

            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Comment: i want to save the config.xml.gpg file in a specific path !! thanks for the reply :)

Comment: this gives me an error saying usage :gpg [options] --encrypt [filename].. can u please help :(

Comment: Try that -o instead of -output